# How to bind JLabel to JSlider using division?

Tags: java, swing, converters, bind, jslider

I need to make a slider that allows user to input a number between 0 and 1 in steps of 0.1. Since JSlider only allows integer values, I gave it a range from 0 to 10 and binded a JLabel to the slider's value. But I want the label to display the decimal number (value/10.0). How can I do that? I am using Netbeans 7.4 GUI editor. When I try to edit the binding expression to ${value}/10 it just appends it as a string. The Component chooser window in converter only says "Custom editing of this property is not supported."
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use BeansBinding: The EL language as realized in BeansBinding library does not support most of the features including primitive calculations. You have to implement a custom `org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Converter` and then add it using "custom code" option: In the converter adding panel, select "Custom code" in converter property combobox, then instantiate your converter in "Property code" text field.

Also, consider writing your own `ChangeListener` that you attach to `JSpinner` which will update the label's text each time the spinner value will change. This is way more easy as I see it. :-)